# What is the default user when running job/playbook from AWX?

Tags: users, ansible-tower

I am running a job/playbook (git source) from AWX GUI, but it keeps connecting over ssh to managed hosts as a root user.

In credentials I filled SSH PRIVATE KEY, USERNAME is blank and the default configuration /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg has not been changed, meaning default remote_user is commented out.

It is a standard AWX installation and there are no additional ansible.cfg files for awx user.
My understanding is that when no user is specified, it should try to connect as current user, i.e. awx.

(ansible 2.9.6)
(AWX 9.3.0)

Where did it pick the root user from?